# Preprocessor flags vs. (e.g.) boolean flags

Tags: optimization, coding-style, preprocessor, flags

I'm familiarizing myself with a scientific hydrodynamics code.  The code almost always uses preprocessor directives, e.g.

```
#ifdef PARTICLES
    int nghost = 5
#else
    int nghost = 4
#endif
```

instead of simpler C flags, like,

```
int nghost = 4;
if( particlesFlag ) { nghost = 5; }
```

The downside of the preprocessor flags is that (in this framework) it requires a configuration (with header file creation) for every problem setup before each build, where as using c-code flags would just require recompilation.

**What are the advantages of this approach?**

It seems like any improvement in efficiency would be incredibly small --- especially since this code (for example) is only being run once when the program is initialized, while all of the real labor is happening in loops across different processors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Say I have thousands of API using nghost. If PARTICLES is defined already, all those variables will be just replaced by 5 else by 4 during preprocessing.

You are talking about a single instance, a big project is where preprocessing is useful.

Think about this.

```
int x() { int a = nghost *5; }
int ab() { return (nghost+10); }
```

Each time, if used, its runtime consuming

```
int x() { 
int a;
int nghost = 4;
if( particlesFlag ) { nghost = 5;}
a=nghost*5;
}


int ab() { 
int nghost = 4;
if( particlesFlag ) { nghost = 5;}
return (nghost+10);
```

}

and so on.

and also think about this.

Assume

```
#ifdef PARTICLES
int nghost = 5
int aghost = 5
int bghost = 5
int cghost = 5
int dghost = 5
int eghost = 5
int fghost = 5
#else
int nghost = 4
int aghost = 4
int bghost = 4
int cghost = 4
int dghost = 4
int eghost = 4
int fghost = 4
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm a little confused.  In the examples I gave, you can translate the first one into `int nghost = 5` (if `PARTICLES` is defined).  So the only difference between the two examples is whether or not you perform the `if...else...` statement during code execution, right?

Comment: when you say if and else, it is during runtime, which is where, your program is expected to be fast. . Preprocessing is when you do your compilation and even before it actually in real time .  .

Comment: Right, I get that.  What I don't get is why **accessing** the variable (`nghost`) is different in the two cases.  I.e. how would `int x() { int a = nghost *5; }` be different if `nghost` was defined via preprocessor vs. in the code?

Comment: runtime is different from compile time. . see my answer for more clarifications. Every time, you have to do a if check whereas if in preprocessing, it is just an arithmetic. .like 5*5 or 4*5

Comment: `nghost` is only defined once.  Each usage of `nghost` should be the same regardless of the two implementations above, right?

Comment: header file is different from a c file.